# How run multiple scripts from one scripts and retrieve results

Tags: python

I have 3 scripts at the end of each script i have a dataframe results and i want to run this 3 scrips from one script and to show results (3 dataframes) that i will regroupe in one dataframe.
If you know how to run this 3 scripts at the same time and get results in one file (Dataframe)

Comment: Have you tried `popen()` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

*Main.py*

```
import pandas as pd
from df_script_1 import script1
from df_script_2 import script2

if __name__ == __main__:
    df1 = script1()
    df2 = script2()
    combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
    print(combined_df)
```

*df_script_1.py*

```
def script1():
   # stuff that makes a DataFrame
   return df
```

*df_script_2.py*

```
def script2():
   # stuff that makes a DataFrame
   return df
```

Answer (score 0):

In scripts make sure you run them inside `if __name__ == __main__:` block(so you don't run then while importing). Turn those scripts into functions (or classes, depending on the structure of your code) and then import them to the main python file. Then write their results to one file inside the main script.